# Segmentación fault

Tags: c++, dev-c++, programación-funcional

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std


int main(int argc, char** argv) 


    int i = 0;

    int ii = 0;

    int j = 0;

    int jj = 0;

    int band = 0;

    int encontrado = 0;

    int* numeros = NULL;

    int* nrepetidos = NULL;

    int n = 0;

    cout<<"Conocer la cantidad de numeros y ordenarlos"<<endl;

    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"ingrese la cantidad de numeros que se usaran";

    cin>>n;

    for(i=0;i<n;i=i+1){
        cout<<"numero"<<i<<". ";
        cin>>numeros[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i=i+1){
        for(j=0;j<n;j=j+1){
            if(numeros[j]<<numeros[j+1]){
                band = numeros[i];
                numeros[j] = numeros[j+1];
                numeros[j] = band;
            }

        }
    }
    for(ii=0;ii<n;ii=ii++){
        if (nrepetidos[ii]=0)
            numeros[ii]= nrepetidos[ii];

        else{

            for(jj=0;jj<n;jj++){
                if(numeros[ii]= nrepetidos[jj]){encontrado = 1;
                }
                if(encontrado=0);{
                    numeros[ii] = nrepetidos[jj];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i=i+1){
    }
    cout<<"Los numeros quedaran odenados de la siguiente manera: "<<nrepetidos<<endl;
    system ("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Alguien me puede ayudar a resolver eso desde  el primer for me sale fragmentación fault, soy nuevo en esto de c++ y no sé qué ha pasado es la primera vez que me sale eso [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 También ya intenté desde mi pc pero sigue apareciendo lo mismo. Lllllllllfjdbdhshshhshshd
Djdjsbdhdhhd
Fjdjdjdjdhdjdbdbdhzhd
Dhdhdhsjdjskdjd
Djdjsksjdbdjdbsksjdhdhdjdksisisbsosbdd
Bsospdbf shsyxtzjzbeifudbeudvdhxjskf djd
( Esto lo agrego por qué no me dejaba publicar )

Comment: El puntero "numeros" nunca cambia su contenido, siempre apunta a NULL. Necesitas reservar un búfer de N elementos de forma dinámica.

Comment: Sube el código escrito, no a través de una imagen al igual que el error que te produce para facilitar la ayuda.

Comment: Youshiro ya subí todo el codigo

Answer (score 1):

```
int* numeros = NULL;

for(i=0;i<n;i=i+1){
    cout<<"numero"<<i<<". ";
    cin>>numeros[i];
}
```

Inicializas `numeros` a `NULL` y después intentas acceder a posiciones de `numeros`... lo raro sería que te funcionase. Los punteros tienen que apuntar a **direcciones válidas** antes de ser utilizados. En caso contrario corres el riesgo de sobreescribir memoria que no te pertenece.

Lo más rápido es usar `new`:

```
cout<<"ingrese la cantidad de numeros que se usaran";

cin>>n;

int* numeros = new int[n]; // <<----

for(i=0;i<n;i=i+1){
    cout<<"numero"<<i<<". ";
    cin>>numeros[i];
}
```

Y luego, por supuesto, hay que acordarse de liberar la memoria

```
cout<<"Los numeros quedaran odenados de la siguiente manera: "<<nrepetidos<<endl;
system ("PAUSE");

delete[] numeros; // <<----

return 0;
```

}